# Stopping infinitive loop in lupa in thread

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading, lupa

I have function, which run some unknown code in LuaRuntime in thread, ex

```
def lua(code):
    lua = LuaRuntime()
    lua.execute(code)

def lua_in_thread(code):
    t = threading.Thread(target = lua, args = (code,))
    t.start()
    return t
```

Where code is

```
a = 1
while a == 1 do end
```

Is there any way to stop the thread? I read about check for variable in condition of infinitive loop, but there code unknown, and I can not guarantee that there will be such a check.

Comment: Not what you asked, but `args = (code)` should be `args = (code,)` to make it a tuple.

Comment: As for the question, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread-in-python

Comment: @zvone About tuple - fixed. About response - i have seen this topic, as I understand - there using condition way. Or i should use raising exception?